# Regular expression to explode CSV data with comma

Tags: php, regex, fgetcsv

I have the following **row** in my CSV file

```
,1,193,23 Video,,"Slotsgade 2, 2.th",,,,,,Copenhagen N,,DK-2200,Denmark,,,,,,,,
,,,Europe,+45 31450980,,info@23company.com,www.23video.com,,,,,,,,Cabsat Online
 Video Industry Sourcebook 12,Mr.,Kristoffer,,Schou,,M,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,schou@23company.com,,,,,,,
```

As you can see

```
"Slotsgade 2, 2.th"
```

has a comma in between, now I am using `preg_split` to explode the row in columns.

Could anyone suggest me a regular expression which skips the comma in between double quotes

I have tried this already:

```
/,|".*(?=")/
```

What is the regular expression that I can use in `preg_split` to get the data correctly?

Comment: Is the question this: "Have I made the question clear enough?"

Comment: :) no its to get the regular expression that I can use in preg_split to get the data correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function, it will deal it for you.

And you also have [str_getcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php), which will parse a CSV string into an array.

Answer (score 0):

From the library of [**RegexBuddy**](http://www.regexbuddy.com/):

> #### CSV: Any field
>
> Matches any single field in a CSV file.  Use this regex to iterate
>   over all fields.
>
> ```
> "[^"\r\n]*"|[^,\r\n]*
> ```
>
> #### CSV: Any field with extra whitespace
>
> Matches any single field in a CSV file.  Use this regex to iterate
>   over all fields. Includes extra whitespace before and after
>   double-quoted fields in the regex match.
>
> ```
> [ \t]*+"[^"\r\n]*+"[ \t]*+|[^,\r\n]*+
> ```
>
> #### CSV: Complete row, all fields
>
> Match complete rows in a comma-delimited file that has 3 fields per
>   row, capturing each field into a backreference.  To match CSV rows
>   with more or fewer fields, simply duplicate or delete the capturing
>   groups.
>
> ```
> ^("[^"\r\n]*"|[^,\r\n]*),("[^"\r\n]*"|[^,\r\n]*),("[^"\r\n]*"|[^,\r\n]*)$
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.....this will definitely be useful, for now the str_getcsv got it working....